# android espresso testing : empty test suite. no tests were found

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am running intelliJ idea 14.0.2 android development environment on windows and am trying to use the espresso UI testing framework to test my app.However when I press run for an androidTest configuration , I encounters the following :

```
Testing started at 12:09 PM ...
Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_5-05b1bd8af0ddba12
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\AsiAnSeNsAtIoN\Documents\note\ECSE428\AssB_2\build\classes\main\AssB_2.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.cyc115.VectorCalculator
Installing com.cyc115.VectorCalculator
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.cyc115.VectorCalculator"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.cyc115.VectorCalculator
Success

Running tests
Test running startedFinish
Empty test suite.
```

this is the screenshot :
[image]

my test class looks like this :

```
package com.cyc115.VectorCalculator.test;

import android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
import com.cyc115.VectorCalculator.MyActivity;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@LargeTest
public class MyActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

    public MyActivityTest(){
        super (MyActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();
        fail();
    }
    @SmallTest
    public void testListGoesOverTheFold() {
        onView(withText("Hello world")).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

here's my project structure just in case :
[image]

my test configuration :
[image]

and my androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.cyc115.VectorCalculator"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>

    <instrumentation
    android:name="android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.cyc115.VectorCalculator"
    />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="com.cyc115.VectorCalculator.MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an workaround: use android-studio based on the community edition of intelliji idea instead of the premium version of intelliji idea. Create a new project and set up espresso from there. More detail refer to the gradle files in the [sample project](https://github.com/cyc115/vectorCalc):

Hope it helps.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Try making a new `Android Instrumented Tests` configuration manually in `Edit Configuration` https://stackoverflow.com/a/53715513/967131

Answer (score -1):

Use annotation @Test before the method , where you have written all the ESPRESSO UI tests. This may work.